# Real analytic way to explain why the radius of convergence of $1/(1+x^2)$ is small

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

For any series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, the disc of convergence is blocked by the two singularities on $+i$ and $-i$. A series expansion about $0$ gives a radius of convergence of $1$.

Is there a way to explain why it is so small with only real analysis?

Comment: You may just compute the coefficients of the Taylor series around $x=0$ and check that the radius of convergence is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it as 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}.
$$
This will lead to a geometric series expansion, which converges when $|-x^2|<1$, i.e. when $|x|<1$.